# How can "unique" show duplicate values in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unique

Background: I am very confused by my dataframe (df), which when I do some simple analyses is producing random rows for a specific value within my column named 'ID' (specifically, when ID == 42). As a result, I have started to do some troubleshooting.

When I try to list all the rows where ID = 42, I do:

```
data=df.loc[df['ID'] == 42]
```

And the rows look correct in this new variable called 'data'. However, when I scroll manually through the original dataframe df (e.g., in the Variable Explorer on Spyder), I can see there are way more rows for ID=42 that are not being printed to 'data'.

Then, to double check why the 'ID' values are showing this weird behavior, I did

```
print(df['ID'].unique())
```

And, weirdly, I get this:

[ 20.  31.  **42.  42.**  84. 142. 198. 248. 280. 288. 352. 378. 459. 498.]
-- note that 42 is repeated!

**My question is,** how can there be two 42s when I use the .unique() function? I thought it was supposed to output all the **unique** values? If I could understand this better, I could start to understand the rest of the problems that ensue...

Am I missing something about how 'unique' works?

Ps. My files are big so I haven't included them, but if I need to provide more (numerical) context please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: It should be float

Comment: Mostly because float does not compare well for equality. There is probably a small difference between your two versions of 42. Which are the answer anyway.

Comment: Similar to the above, if you use this `print(df['ID'].astype(int).unique())`, do you still get a strange result?

Comment: As a reminder never use float as a key (eg for indexing) mainly for this reason.

Comment: Hi @SRawson, thanks for the code. When I do that 42 only shows up once!
I thought I had avoided having my ID's as a float by using:

 df['ID'] = pd.to_numeric(df['ID']), but they were still showing up as floats... 

I had tried: 
df['ID'] = df['ID'].astype(int), before but this gave me the error:

Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer. 
Thanks for the assistance, I will see what I can do from here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving my comment to an answer, as it solved the problem:

```
print(df['ID'].astype(int).unique())
```

Comment: Thanks, I now did
`df = df.dropna(subset = ["ID"])` followed by 
`df['ID'] = df['ID'].astype(int)`
before my analysis, and all my problems are solved. Thank you!